# how to convert this sql query to liquibase query

Tags: sql, database, liquibase

I have table like this

```
|-------------------------|
|   A   |   B   |    V    |
|-------------------------|
|   1   |   2   |    5    |
|-------------------------|
|   1   |   2   |    10   |
|-------------------------|
|   1   |   2   |    2    |
|-------------------------|
```

I need to delete all duplicated rows with equals A nad B value and lower C value

after running sql script i need to have only this row with top C Value for every equals A and B columns

```
|-------------------------|
|   A   |   B   |    V    |
|-------------------------|
|   1   |   2   |    10   |
|-------------------------|
```

this is the sql query i am using

```
delete from t where t.v < (select max(t2.v) from t t2 where t2.a = t.a and t2.b = t.b);
```

how to convert it to liquibase query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
<changeSet  author="liquibase-docs"  id="delete-example">  
    <delete  catalogName="cat"  
            schemaName="public"  
            tableName="t">  
        <where>t.v &lt; (select max(t2.v) from t t2 where t2.a = t.a and t2.b = t.b)</where>  
    </delete>  
</changeSet>
```

Comment: yes, but  i think second where should be in <where> tag

Comment: No. Why. This is a subselect that forms the whole where statement

Comment: Because i cant build project and the error is  "The content of elements must consist of well-formed charachter data or markup"

Comment: That's because of the `<` in `where` tag. The xml gets broken. Just swap the condition to convert `<` to `>=`

Comment: Oh yes I changed my answer to make it XML complient

Comment: Or use a `CDATA` section